# What algorithms available in weka automatically weights the features of the dataset?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, weka

I have a data-set with between 5 to 10 features. The output value is a scalar value. (So I look something like a linear regression, not a classifier). Some features are more important that others, and some combinations of features can give a large outcome.

What algorithms built in Weka are good candidates given those requirements ?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try "Select attributes" tab in Weka Explorer?
InfoGainAttributeEval and CorrelationAtrributeEval are two useful feature selection methods I usually start with.

Here is an example output from the InfoGainAttributeEval against my dataset. The first column list the importance of each attribute in descending order.

```
Ranked attributes:
0.02416    8 attr8
0.014166  16 attr16
0.012868  14 attr14
0.011905  15 attr15
0.011624   6 attr6
0.010619   1 attr1
0.010367   3 attr3
0.010171   5 attr5
0.008921   7 attr7
0.008763  11 attr11
0.006094   9 attr9
0.00603   10 attr10
0.003089   4 attr4
0.00095   12 attr12
0.000672   2 attr2
0.000127  13 attr13

Selected attributes: 8,16,14,15,6,1,3,5,7,11,9,10,4,12,2,13 : 16
```

If you have interest, please refer to below link for a classical thesis about correlation-based feature selection:
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~mhall/thesis.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Weka has a set of "`Classifier`"s which perform regression (they output a numeric "class" in Weka terminology). In the Weka GUI, you'll see them if you select a numeric attribute as the "class".

Among them is `weka.classifiers.functions.SimpleLinearRegression`, which does exactly what it says. Weka also has more complex regression engines, such as the `MultilayerPerceptron`.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think he is looking for "which feature is better", but more to the weights (theta values) to give to each feature when using [linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). Not sure I am correct though. (Note that the weights given to each feature in AttributeSelection denotes its importance - and not how to use it, an attribute can have high negative correlation to the output value - and the AttributeSelection will give it high score, while if I understood correctly, he is looking for a negative weight in this case)

Comment: Maybe I misread the question. However, Weka already has a linear regression algorithm...I'm surprised OP didn't run across it if that's what he's looking for.

Comment: Tell you the truth - I never used Weka's `LinearRegression` - but since it is an instance of Classifier, I suspect it uses a linear regression algorithm in order to predict a *class* of the instance - and not predict its "score" - I'll be glad to learn if you know the answer :|

Comment: @amit I am indeed looking for `the weights (theta values) to give to each feature when using linear regression`. In my case, there is no such thing as a negative weight having negative correlation to the output, but I definitely have high positive correlation on some parameters. Eg, some parameters have a very high impact on the output compared to others.

Comment: @amit: It's a `Classifier`, but it only works for predicting numeric values (i.e. continuous data, not classes). Weka's terminology is unusual in that regard.

Comment: @nneonneo: Thank you for the information. It is unconventional terminology... :| Please edit the answer (according to the comment of pinouchon, it is indeed what he is after) with some explanation and conclusions from out little discussion. (going to sleep now, I'll be glad to upvote an editted answer tomorrow morning, I promise that) :)